# Python AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'atoi'

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to run following program of using python 3.2 , there is error:
 'module' object has no attribute 'atoi'
 Can anybody tell me what should I do to fix this?
i really appreciate it !

```
import string
def converttoint(str):
    try:
        value = string.atoi(str)
        return value
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`string.atoi` has been deprecated for a *very* long time.  Since [Python 2.0](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.atoi), in fact, and it doesn't exist in Python 3.

Simply use

```
value = int(s)
```

instead, and don't call your variable `str`.  That's a bad habit, as it shadows the builtin string type `str`.

Comment: Python3 says from `int('@')`: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '@'`.

Comment: Because you can't turn "a" into a integer. "1" on the other hand...